# Como criar sobrecarga em PHP por meio de variadic-function?

Tags: php, sobrecarga

**Eis o meu problema :** por questões de `debug` eu decidi criar uma função que me retornasse um `print_r` formatado sem a necessidade de uma *gambiarra* (isto é, sem criar os `<pre>/<pre>`. Dessa forma, eu transformaria isso:

```
<?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($array);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Em isso:

```
<?php printr($array); //onde a função *printr* foi criada por mim. ?>
```

Mas... Para mim isso não era suficiente, eu queria ter dois métodos `printr`: um que recebesse apenas um parâmetro e de fato imprimisse na tela; outro que recebesse dois parâmetros, onde um escrevesse uma mensagem como *Debug do Sistema* , e outro que imprimisse o `print_r` da maneira que desejava.
Eis que eu me pergunto, como que eu faço isso, sabendo que o **PHP** não permite que eu crie dois métodos com o mesmo nome?

Comment: Pode ser o que você queria, mas isso nada tem a ver com sobrecarga.

Comment: Então acho que meus conceitos estão errados, poderia você criar um exemplo utilizando esse conceito?

Comment: Sou novato na área, e essa foi a unica forma que eu encontrei de solucionar esse problema

Comment: PHP não pode ter sobrecarga.

Comment: Exatamente! Essa foi a única forma eficiente que eu encontrei de _driblar_ esse problema.

Comment: Volte para meu primeiro comentário, entramos em *loop*.

Answer (score 0):

Eis que eu encontro minha resposta : `variadic-function`.
Basicamente, o **PHP** tem um recurso no qual eu não delimito o numero de parâmetros dentro da minha função. Isso faz com que eu possa colocar um numero diferente de parâmetros por chamada, o que era exatamente o que eu queria!
A sintaxe básica desse conceito seria:

```
<?php
   /*
    Esses 3 pontinhos simbolizam basicamente, que todos os elementos que
    eu colocar dentro dessa variável será armazenado em um array com o 
    limite sendo a quantidade de parâmetros utilizados.
   */
   function valores(...$parametros){
      foreach($parametros as $chave => $valor){
         echo "O parametro".$chave."é:".$valor;
      }

     $a = valores("Hello"); //essa função retorna "O Parametro 0 é Hello".
     $b = valores("Hello","World"); // essa função retorna "O Parametro 0 é Hello.O Parametro 1 é World".
   }
?>
```

Sendo assim, agora é só colocar os valores que eu quero que ele imprime, certo?

```
public function valores(...$parameter){
    if(count($parameter) == 1){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($parameter[0]);
        echo "</pre>";
    } else if (count($parameter) == 2){
        echo "<h1>";
        echo $parameter[0];
        echo "</h1>";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($parameter[1]);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Essa função funciona perfeitamente! Qualquer dica/opinião é bem-vinda! Espero que compartilhem seus conhecimentos comigo também